# Determining IP address subnet addres

Tags: networking, ip

Having an arbitrary public IP address is there a way to determine the subnet it belongs to whithout knowing the net-mask?

Comment: No. I've always felt that the CIDR crowd is overloud in declaring subnetting a dead art, but in this case, it is absolutely true. From a CIDR perspective, a host exists in every mask for that range larger than its own mask, and as such it doesn't actually have a single static subnet it belongs to.

Comment: [This answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) is an excellent explanation of IP addressing.

Comment: Simply put, the netmask defines the size of the network, so if you don't have it, you have no way of knowing where the boundaries are.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.

The best you can do is make educated guesses - how educated depends on how desperate you are and what resources you have at your disposal.

Sources to inform the guess would include (but are probably not limited to)

1. Hints from the IP address - at least in NZ, historically addresses were
   broken down into size ranges (smallest being a "Class C" of 256).
2. What BGP routing tables tell you.
3. As per @Zina post - how the gateway and host responds.  There are 
   gotchas here and it is unreliable at best.  Assumptions about the next
   hop are not always valid - although you can improve upon this if you
   can do fingerprinting of the devices and see if the same router is
   responding on multiple addresses and infer subnetting from that.
4. By taking hints from the services available from the devices behind
   the router in the same subnet - again, highly unreliable, but, for 
   example, a cloud service might have multiple instances of the same
   web server set up the same way, and its neighbours - which might belong
   to other tenants would have different configs.
5. The last octet also tells you something.  Certain values are more
   likely to act "differently" to regular addresses (broadcast and network)
   and this might also help infer it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to find it with traceroute. Find your public gateway with `traceroute www.google.com`. Now just traceroute the previous / next IP starting from the public DG. When you start to see a additional hop that will show you the boundary. Eg. my IP is x.y.96.112 and my router shows that the DG is 96.1. and I see the same with the traceroute google check, first hop local router IP, next hop public gateway IP. So I know it is at least a /25 network (First IP -> 1 - my public IP -> 112 - meaning at least a network with 126 hosts). With traceroute I see an additional hop on x.y.95.254 (so the DG on 96.1 is the first IP in the network) and an additional hop with x.y.98.1 - so I assume it is a /22 network. Of course this works only if you get a reply with IP address from the hops.